# index rspec test failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

Im having difficulties with writing a spec for an index action of a controller im trying to test. The controller looks like this:

```
class MyGamesResultsController < ApplicationController
   def index
    @contest = Contest.find(params[:contest_id])
    @my_entry = current_user.entries.where(contest_id: params[:contest_id])
    @points_per_player = @my_entry[0].points_per_player
    @total_points = @my_entry[0].total_points
   end
end
```

and my spec looks like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyGamesResultsController, type: :controller do
   describe 'GET /index' do
      let!(:user) { create(:user) }

      before :each do
       sign_in user
       get :index
      end

   it 'renders the index template' do
    expect(subject).to render_template(:index)
   end
  end
 end
```

The error that the spec returns says this:

Failure/Error: get :index
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
Couldn't find Contest with 'id'=

Can anyone figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Your test simulate a GET request to `/index` but in your Controller you use `params[:contest_id]` to find a Contest record. Are you sure this `contest_id` is given in the params hash in your test?

Comment: I don't think the contest_id is given in the params hash in my test. How do I do that? Im sorry I should have mentioned that I'm new to rails

Comment: I think it is as simple as the following: `get :index, contest_id: some_id` (where the variable `some_id` contains an actual Contest id, which you can find before calling the `get`)

Comment: is there a way to mock this or something?

Comment: a pretty straight-forward way to do this : `get :index, contest_id: Contest.first.id`

Comment: I now get this error:

Failure/Error: get :index, contest_id: Contest.first.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `points_per_player' for nil:NilClass

Comment: This happens because of the line `current_user.entries.where(contest_id: params[:contest_id])` returns no result at all, therefore is an empty array, and then calling `points_per_player` on the first element of an empty array raises "undefined method points_per_player for nil"

Comment: Isnt it more a case of having to mock out the @my_entry instance variable?

Comment: it is about the piece of code relying of the fact that for the `contest_id` you give to the app, it will ALWAYS find at least one `entry` matching the `current_user` AND the given `contest_id`. In your test case, it does not. Change to `get :index, contest_id: current_user.entries.first.contest_id` to respect the conditions of the index action implementation

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! had to do this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe MyGamesResultsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET index" do

   let!(:user) { create(:user) }
   let!(:contest) { create(:contest) }
   let!(:my_entry) { create(:entry, user_id: user.id, contest_id: contest.id) }


   before :each do
     sign_in user
     get :index, contest_id: contest.id
   end

   it "renders the index template" do
    (expect (response.status)).to eql(200) 
   end
 end
end
```